# How to subset ffdf by index?

Tags: r, ff, ffbase

**I would like to subset an ffdf object by index, returning another ffdf object.**

The [help file on subset.ffdf](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ffbase/versions/0.12.3/topics/subset.ff) indicates that you can pass a range index (ri) object as an argument, but when I tried:

```
data_subset <- subset.ffdf(data, ri(1, 1e5))
```

I got this error:

```
Error in which(eval(e, nl, envir)) : argument to 'which' is not logical
```

Per You-Leee's suggestion, I tried passing a logical vector of the index of interest with this code:

```
n <- length(data[[1]]) #10.5 million
logical_index = c(1, 1e5) == seq.int(1, n)
data_subset <- subset(data, logical_index)
```

I tried to run it twice and each time my R-Studio crashed with the message `R encountered a fatal error.  The session was terminated.` At first I thought it might be a memory constraint, but looking at my activity monitor, I still have 4gb available out of 8gb.  And besides, this shouldn't be loading much into memory anyway.

Comment: The second element of `subset` needs to be a condition i.e. a logical vector (TRUE, FALSE). Do you want to subset columns by index?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I would like, subset by index.

Answer (score 0):

The argument has to be logical, so you have to put TRUE on the desired indices and FALSE otherwise:

```
> data <- ffdf(a = ff(1:12))
> subset.ffdf(data, c(1, 1e5) == seq.int(1, length(data$a)))
ffdf (all open) dim=c(1,1), dimorder=c(1,2) row.names=NULL
ffdf virtual mapping
  PhysicalName VirtualVmode PhysicalVmode  AsIs VirtualIsMatrix     PhysicalIsMatrix
a            a      integer       integer FALSE           FALSE                FALSE
  PhysicalElementNo PhysicalFirstCol PhysicalLastCol PhysicalIsOpen
a                 1                1               1           TRUE
ffdf data
  a
1 1
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, You-leee! Please check out my edit to the question.

Comment: I think this calls for a new question, because of the fatal error.
Since there is no other error message, I would start by debugging the subset function: '> debug(subset.ffdf)' and then get as deep in the function calls as possible to determine, where the fatal error is thrown.